# Run local docker container that can be SSHed into

Tags: docker, capistrano

I want to test some changes to a Capistrano application. I want to run a docker container locally that my application can SSH into, so I can run commands against the container and observe what happens.

I was looking at https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/. I can ssh into via `ssh root@localhost -p 49154`, but I need to be able to access via it's IP and port `22`, e.g. `ssh root@172.17.0.2` but this will time out.

I suspect I need to do some docker network type stuff to get this working. Any ideas?

Comment: You’ll need to do some major reworking of your image layout to make it possible to ssh into it, and do some complex setup to manage credentials securely.  (Neither the user password nor the host key can be stored in the image.)  A virtual machine is probably a better match for this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the Capistrano documentation I realize I can just give the port when I define the role. So I can bring up the container with

```
docker run -d -P -p 32770:22 --name server rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:14.04
```

And attach to it with:

```
role :cost_app, "root@localhost:32770"
```

Comment: When you start the container adding keys is also handy `ssh-copy-id root@localhost -p 32770`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

This will essentially get you the shell of the container and enable you to see what goes on inside the container and debug it.